# AES/CBC/PKCS5Padding encrypt different result between android4.4 and pre versions

Tags: java, android, encryption

I use aes-cbc-pkcs5padding to encode a password,the code below works in android4.4 or higher version,but in android4.2 ,it returns a different result every time. Can anybody teach me how to solve the problem? Thanks.

```
public  String encryptPass(){

    String username="stackoverflow";
    String password="stackoverflow";
    String salt="stackoverflow145";

    /* generate secretkey */
    PBEKeySpec keySpec=new PBEKeySpec(username.toCharArray(),salt.getBytes(),1000,256);
    SecretKeyFactory keyFactory=SecretKeyFactory.getInstance("PBKDF2WithHmacSHA1");
    SecretKey key=keyFactory.generateSecret(keySpec);

    /* IV bytes 16 length */
    byte[] iv={0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0}
    IvParameterSpec ivSpec=new IvParameterSpec(iv);

    Cipher cipher=Cipher.getInstance("AES/CBC/PKCS5Padding");
    cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE,key,ivSpec);
    byte[] passBytes=cipher.doFinal(password.getBytes());
    String result=Base64.encodeToString(passBytes,Base64.NO_WRAP);
    return result;
}
```

I try to add code:cipher.getProvier.getName() to test, then i found that in android4.4 or higher version, it shows "AndroidOpenSSL"; Below 4.4 it was "BC". Does it matter in the problem?May someone help me? Thanks.

Comment: Hex dump the key to see if it the same.

Comment: `PBEKeySpec(username.toCharArray,salt.getBytes()` should result in a compiler error, because there is no such field `toCharArray`. You want to add `()`, which leads me to believe that there is something missing in your actual code, because this should work. Please add better code that would exhibit your issue.

Comment: I miss the"()" in my code,but the problem is not that.The code can work in android4.4 or higher version,but in pre-android4.4 version ,like android4.2,the secret key is same,but the result is change every time.I think the problem is in the Cipher.init,it create a default SecureRandom.I have added codes in my application like http://android-developers.blogspot.com.au/2013/08/some-securerandom-thoughts.html says.But it didn't work.@ArtjomB.

Answer (score 0):

Finally,i transform secretKey to secretKeySpec,which works all android versions.Codes like below:

```
/* generate secretkey */
PBEKeySpec keySpec=new PBEKeySpec(username.toCharArray(),salt.getBytes(),1000,256);
SecretKeyFactory keyFactory=SecretKeyFactory.getInstance("PBKDF2WithHmacSHA1");
SecretKey tmp=keyFactory.generateSecret(keySpec);

/*transform key to keySpec*/
SecretKey key=new SecretKeySpec(tmp.getEncoded(),"AES");
```

May somebody tell me why? I test to  change the algorithm "AES" with "DES",but finally the result didn't change.That's weired.